# How to set test file path for MbUnit tests with Gallio via NAnt?

Tags: file, nant, mstest, mbunit, gallio

Please excuse the ambiguous title; it's difficult to describe in a single line.

Basically we have MbUnit tests which run fine using TestDriven from within Visual Studio, but fails when attempting to run the tests via the <gallio> task from within NAnt.

The failure are to do with the tests which attempt to read files; they read files relative to the current directory, for example "..\..\files\dir\whatever". However the problem seems to be that Gallio copies the test DLLs to a directory elsewhere, and sets the current directory to be "%HOMEDIR%\AppData\Local\Temp\Gallio\MSTestAdapter\randomname\TestDir\Out\something".

So my question is two-fold: Where should I be putting files which are required by tests so they can be found at runtime, and how should I be referring to them from code?

(Also, I didn't think we were using MS-Test at all, so how come there's an 'MSTest' directory in there?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although we use NUnit instead of MbUnit I think there is some general advice I can give regarding handling files in unit tests.

Never rely on paths - neither absolute nor relative. Keep control over paths inside your tests. This is what we do:

1. Add a folder named `Resources` to your test project (so you have everything in one place)
2. Put required files in there (e.g. `MyFile.txt`)
3. Add the files to your project via `Add` > `Existing Item...` (so your files are kept with your sources. They get deployed afterwards as part of the assembly of your test project)
4. Add the files to your test project's resources (tab `Resources` in the project's properties, `Add Resource` > `Add Existing File...`)
5. Use the file in your test fixture:

   1. Define a file path field in your fixture class (use `Path.GetTempFileName()` since you have a unique path then and it's most likely you have sufficient access rights on any machine)
   2. Create a local file using the file path during test setup
   3. Use the file in your test
   4. Delete the created file during tear down

Here is a sample:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyFixture
{
  private static readonly string MyFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

  [SetUp]
  public void SetUp()
  {
    // use File.WriteAllBytes for binary files
    File.WriteAllText(MyFilePath, Properties.Resources.MyFile);
  }

  [Test]
  public void TestSomething()
  {
    Assert.That(ObjectUnderTest.UseFile(MyFilePath), Is.True);
  }

  [TearDown]
  public void TearDown()
  {
    File.Delete(MyFilePath);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that seems sensible. If I was _writing_ files in a test, I would use `Path.GetTempFileName()` anyway, but I guess I was being lazy by avoiding adding resources for all the test files I’m _reading_!